# Value is getting undefined after passing it to other argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm 6 weeks in to a html/css/javascript course and I need to build a movie filter using a switch statement. I'm stuck and I don't know what to do.

I wrote this code (could be complete garbage, don't blame the noob):

```
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[name="film-filter"]');

function addEventListeners() {

    for (let counter = 0; counter < radioButtons.length; counter++) {
        radioButtons[counter].addEventListener("change", event => {
            const radioValue = event.target.value;
            /* console.log(radioValue); */
            addHandleToChange();
        });

    };


};

function addHandleToChange(radioValue) {
    console.log(radioValue);
};

addEventListeners();
```

I'm trying to the pass the const radioValue to the second function, the addHandleToChange. In this function I want to create my switch statement so I can start filtering the big movie Javascript file they provided using the radioValue const. But the console keeps saying the radioValue is undefined. Functions have stupid names but I have to keep these names.

Hopefully my question kind of straight to the point. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't passed `radioValue` to `addHandleToChange`. Do it as `addHandleToChange(radioValue)`...

Comment: See, still learning haha! That actually worked, lot's of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass radioValue to function,
addHandleToChange(radioValue);